# Formula Field and Using the FLOOR and CEILING function

Tags: visualforce, formula, formula-field

I have a formula field that works perfectly except in the condition when the arithmetic returns a number less than 1 such as 0.24, the floor function is rounding it down to 0.  For my requirement, if the number is less than 1, I want it to use CEILING, but I can't get the syntax correct.

```
IF(
End_Date__c - Start_Date__c <= 27,
FLOOR( Orders_Per_Month__c *((End_Date__c - Start_Date__c)/27)), 
Orders_Per_Month__c 
)
```

When the End_Date__c - Start_Date__c <= 27, for example, a 1 or 2-day difference, then the arithmetic ends up returning a number less than 1 when I divide by 27, it is in this scenario I want to somehow use the CEILING function to return 1.

Part of my problem is I can't store the output of End_Date__c minus Start_Date__c into a variable due this being a formula field versus Apex.  If I could, I would then just use as a way to build a condition around when to use the FLOOR function vs when to use the CEILING function.

How can modify the formula to incorporate the CEILING function for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas do tend to lead to a lot of repetition.

If you really just need to make sure that the minimum number returned is 1, then the `MAX()` function can help you out.

Something like

```
MAX(
    1, 
    FLOOR( Orders_Per_Month__c *((End_Date__c - Start_Date__c)/27))
)
```

If `Orders_Per_Month__c *((End_Date__c - Start_Date__c)/27)` < 1, then 1 will be the maximum, and thus the number that gets returned.

You may need to play with *where* you place the `MAX()` function (depending on precisely what result you're looking for, there's not enough information in your question to know that for sure), but it really doesn't need to be that complicated.